# jQuery load: Loading a single file for many purposes?

Tags: jquery, select, load

I have few select's which their content is loaded on DOM ready.

It looks something like this:

```
<select id="select1"> </select>
<select id="select2"> </select>
<select id="select3"> </select>
<select id="select4"> </select>
<select id="select5"> </select>
```

and the javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#select1").load("select1.html", 
             function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
               if (textStatus == "success") {
                     alert("success");
               }     
    }); 


$("#select2").load("select2.html", 
                 function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                   if (textStatus == "success") {
                         alert("success");
                   }     
        });
    // and goes on for every select
```

EDIT:

Now, each select has different values. Select1 for countries, Select2 for colours, Select3 for currency etc. **How can I combine all the options into 1 HTML/XML and load for each select its options from that 1 file.**

Question 2: Is it better to load each select options its own file or have everything combined?

Note that now the content is loaded on DOM ready; for test purpose. In the feature I will be calling each select content separately. The reason I am loading the options is because each select has about 30 options and I want to reduce the loading time since the entire site its a 1 page dashboard web app with many select options.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to put each select in a different file ? I can't see why you would want that.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder each select have different options. The one is few countries, the other is color's for example etc.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder and I don't want that. I want all select's in same file, which that is my question sir. How can I do that?

Comment: The one way i can think of is you can load page fragments using jquery. Although that would request the whole html fine anyways,  the only other way i can think is using server side scripting such as php to send back only the required drop down html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just load **fragments** from a single page.

Do it like this

`$("#select1").load("select.html #select1_content",  //continue`

In this way, you are loading into `#select1` the contents of the `#select1_content` from your single `select.html` page.

See *Loading Page Fragments* here: http://api.jquery.com/load/